# Character Rigging Best Practices regarding modifiers

Tags: animation, modifiers, rigging

I have a character modelled and ready to rig. I was wondering if there is any reason to avoid rigging/animating with things like the mirror modifier NOT being applied.

Is this "bad practice"? Will it cause issues for future me?

I'm kind of learning as I'm going and I haven't seen anyone mention whether things like this are good or bad. If I can avoid applying the modifier then I'm assuming that will make it easier to make tweaks and change the character model later if I need to.

Cheers.

Comment: My immediate thought if you have an unapplied mirror modifier on a model which is going to be rigged is that you're not going to be able to move each side of the model independently. Moving the "real" side is going to move the mirrored side too so, for instance, you won't be able to move the legs independently if you want to create a walk cycle!

Comment: So far that all seems fine. I've mirrored the bones in the armature and the weights are automatically applied to the correct leg. So if I weight paint the left leg to the left bones then that is mirrored to the right. Moving the bones moves the correct part of the body. 

The only negative I've found so far is that for simple elements of the mesh, like an eyebrow I can't simply select it and assign the right eyebrow to a bone group because the right eyebrow doesn't exist in edit mode, it's just a mirror.

Comment: Is there a reason why you don't what to apply the mirror modifier? I haven't seen any professionally rigged models (e.g from Blender Studio) that had not applied the mirror modifier. My experience is that there are disadvantages. For example, you cannot rig the eyes properly with a mirror modifier. There are stacked UV islands. So you can't texture paint the sides differently and you cannot use the new hair curves.

Comment: Hey @Blunder. The main reasons were those I've mentioned. If I needed to come back and make edits later, tweak the design of the character a little etc. then it's easier to have the mirror modifier still there. When sending it to a game engine I apply the modifiers then through the export process. 

I haven't yet seen any negatives but I also haven't added things like hair as it's quite stylized.